# Raspberry PI3 Windows 10 IoT Core Turn HDMI screen off when no activity

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, hdmi

We have a PI 3 running a UWP app in our company. There is no mouse or keyboard connected. There is a touch screen connected to the HDMI output.
Is there a way the screen can be turned off automatically when there is no activity for a specified amount of time?
I used hdmi_blanking=1 in the config.txt but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Maybe this would be more relevant on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Cœur: Thanks, I really should have checked that. I prefer mine brown and crunchy when it pops up! (I love toast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way the screen can be turned off automatically when there
>   is no activity for a specified amount of time?

You can use powercfg tool and have a try. I test with the [official 7″ touchscreen](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/) and it works for me.(Windows IoT Core version is 10.0.17083.1000)

For example, set the time to 60 seconds like this:

```
powercfg  /setacvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e 60
powercfg  /setdcvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e 60
```

Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)

Subgroup GUID: 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99  (Display)

Power Setting GUID: 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e  (Turn off display after)

**Note:** These settings need a reboot to take action.

For more information, you can reference "[Powercfg command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options#option_aliases)".

Answer (score 0):

There is a long MSDN Forum thread discussing exactly this problem [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7289a3f7-2926-497d-957d-4df02f1e3452/turn-off-monitor?forum=WindowsIoT).

The takeaway is that there is not built-in UWP API that allows you to turn screen off, but the support may be available in the hardware driver itself and you would need a way to call this native interface.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I already read that article. The last post dates back to April 2017. Almost a year ago.

Comment: I am afraid not much has changed since that time

Comment: I'm looking also into this, turning off does work, but is there any way to torn it back on via powercfg or something else, which is accessible from code or command line?